# javascript visual studio 2013 indentation

Tags: visual-studio, editor, visual-studio-2013

I started playing around with javascript on Visual Studio 2013 and I couldn't figure out why it is not automatically positioning the cursor to the correct indentation level, instead always resetting back to the head. For example:

```
function foo(y) {
    var f = function bar(x) {
    |<-- cursor should be here, but ends up
|<-- over here
}
```

Does anyone else see this and how do you change it?

I have the typescript, nodejs plugin installed and that's about it.

Comment: I have this problem too, indentation doesn't seem to be working until you hit a format trigger like `} ; Enter Paste`

Comment: Did you get a solution to this issue? This is annoying me enough that I started looking for solution and ended up here. I am using VS Express and see the same behavior.

Comment: Nope, no updates on this. I have moved on to a mac :)

Answer (score 14):

With a bit of research, things started working for me. First check that, Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> Javascript -> Tabs -> Indenting is set to 'Smart'. Next restart VS. For me restarting was important since, apparently, my file had some mixed line-endings and that was throwing off the indentation engine. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Stopped working for me too.  I closed and re-opened just the document (instead of VS) and it started working again.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the whole javascript formatting stopped working for every file, I could play with language options and restart VS, nothing helped, until I unchecked:

```
Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> JavaScript/TypeScript -> Language Service -> Enable the new JavaScript language service
```

The editor returned to old school javascript formatting, which is sufficient for me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this applies to Visual Studio 2013 (the original question), but in 2015 at least, you can select the text in your JavaScript file you want to format, right-click, and then choose "Format Selection".  There's a keyboard short-cut as well (Ctrl-K, Ctrl-F).

Answer (score 0):

1. If you already have Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> Javascript -> Tabs -> Indenting set to 'Smart', then try setting this option (the Indenting setting) to 'None' and click OK.
2. Open the Options back up and, set Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> Javascript -> Tabs -> Indenting back to 'Smart', click OK.
3. Close and reopen the file you were working on.